# How to read the files inside of a tar file without untaring it?

Tags: import

I have a tra.gz file which contains many ascii format files insdie. I would like to read those ascii files without untaring the actual tar file. I know it can be done in python easily but is it possible in Mathematica? Thanks

Comment: `Import["test.tar", "*"]` from the documentation (search "tar")

Comment: Thanks a lot Carl Lange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an experimental tar file:

```
Export["a.txt", "bla"];
Export["b.txt", "blubb"];
Run["tar -cf a.tar a.txt b.txt"]
DeleteFile[{"a.txt", "b.txt"}];
```

> 0

`0` means, it worked out.

Now try

```
Import["a.tar", "a.txt"]
(* import all files as shown by Carl Lange*)
Import["a.tar", "*"]
FileExistsQ /@ {"a.txt", "b.txt"}
```

> "bla"
>
> {"bla", "blubb"}
>
> {False, False}

So none of the files `"a.txt"` or `"b.txt"` have been untared to files - at least not into the working directory...

Afterwards, ypu can delete the file with `DeleteFile["a.tar"]`.

Comment: I'm Carl Lange, not Carl Woll ;)

Comment: @CarlLange  Sorry, that was kind of a habit... =D

Comment: Thanks Henrik for explaining it in detail.

Comment: @ssb You're welcome.